@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/PeoplePicker control return only one value at a time i need object of username and email
in @pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/PeoplePicker control when i select one user that control return object but when i edit manage content selected user not display in peoplepiker control
i need object of username and email and update people piker control in manage content custom control
this is PeoplePiker control
{
id: EVENTS_MANAGE_CONTENT_FIELD_KEY_VALUE.PUBLISH_BY_ID,
title: EVENTS_MANAGE_CONTENT_FIELD_KEY_VALUE.PUBLISH_BY_LABEL,
type: CustomCollectionFieldType.custom,
required: DEFAULT_DATA_TYPE_VALUE.TRUE,
onCustomRender: (field, value, onUpdate, item, itemId, onError) => {
return React.createElement(PeoplePicker, {
context: this.context as any,
personSelectionLimit: 1,
showtooltip: DEFAULT_DATA_TYPE_VALUE.TRUE,
key: itemId,
defaultSelectedUsers: item?.customFieldId,
onChange: (items: any = []) => {
const { text, secondaryText } = items[0];
item.customFieldId = [{ text: text, secondaryText: secondaryText }];
onUpdate(field?.id, [{ text: text, secondaryText: secondaryText }]);
},
showHiddenInUI: DEFAULT_DATA_TYPE_VALUE.FALSE,
principalTypes: [PrincipalType.User],
});
},
},

